# Can eclipse generate portable makefiles?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

The makefiles generated by eclipse contain absolute paths, such as `-I"/home/user/workspace/project/subdir/include"`. This happens although I used `${workspace_loc:/project/include}` when defining the include directory.

Is there a way to generate portable makefiles that can be used on a different machine resp. a different user (one without eclipse)?

Comment: You wan to run an app on every computer? You generate a war file?

Comment: Have you considered other alternatives to CDT-generated Makefiles, e.g. CMake with CDT generator. Thus you'll get a decently portable project suitable for various IDEs, including KDevelop,QtCreator and (to some extent) MSVS

Comment: @Soma likely if he/she needs Makefile's then he/she works with CDT and depelops a C/C++ application. So no war anymore :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting CMake